# Project summary - Source code lines

Tags: code-statistics

I'm looking for a tool that would count the number of files, the number of lines (with or without comments) and possibly other statistics for my project in PHP and JavaScript.

Notes:

- I've already found [SLOCCount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) which seems quite nice. It requires Cygwin.
- Yes, I can wrote a simple script for basic information but I'm looking for something more complex.

Do you know about alternatives for Windows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) is a very nice Perl script (available in a standalone Windows executable too) that will break down how many lines of your files are blank, comments, or actual source.  It also shows those statistics by file type.